# Quickly determine if vectors are independent

Tags: linear-programming, linear-independence

Just trying to determine if two vectors are independent or dependent. Instead of computing the cross product or dot product, faster to just go element by element and see if the common factor between all the elements is the same (?).

```
const areIndependent = (a: Array<number>, b: Array<number>) => {

    let firstFactor = math.divide(a[0], b[0]);

    for(let j = 1; j < a.length; j++){
        if(math.divide(a[j],b[j]) !== firstFactor){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

the above should work, but I realized that dividing by zero will be a problem. If the denominator is zero, how do I handle this properly? Not sure.

Comment: What's wrong with handling this as a special case when you first calculate the first factor, and later when doing the division? The speed of a check like that is pretty negligible (especially when compared to doing a division)

Comment: What is JS in this context ? I know the domain of Linear Programming but I had never seen this acronym...

Comment: The problem is dividing by zero, and if both a[j] = 0 and b[j] = 0, I don't know how to handle those cases properly. JS is javascript.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Javascript to know: what is `number`?  If it's a machine floating point number, then rounding errors will make this function pretty much useless.  If it's an exact representation of a rational number, though, that should be fine.

Comment: I use mathjs which does some magic with number comparison, assume like working numbers mathematical not so much computational or what not

Comment: I have understood now that JS=Java Script. Not in connection with Linear Programming. But why haven't you answered me ? You would have lost 1 mn of your time...

Comment: I did answer you, look in a previous comment, sorry it wasn't clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code is OK as is. But we can add stuff to be more explicit:

```
const areIndependent = (a: Array<number>, b: Array<number>) : Boolean => {

    if(a[0] !== 0 && b[0] === 0){
        // if one elem is 0 and the other is not, then they always LI
        return true;
    }

    if(a[0] === 0 && b[0] !== 0){
        return true;
    }

    const firstFactor = math.divide(a[0],b[0]);

    for(let j = 1; j < a.length; j++){

        if(a[j] === 0 && b[j] !== 0){
            return true;
        }

        if(a[j] !== 0 && b[j] === 0){
            return true;
        }

        const currFactor = math.divide(a[j], b[j]);
        if(!math.equal(currFactor,firstFactor)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

this should be a lot faster than the cross product or dot product if you just want to find out if two vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: `// if one elem is 0 and the other is not, then they always LI` not necessarily, if one of the vectors is the zero vector.

Comment: is the zero vector not LI with a non-zero vector?

Comment: The zero vector is automatically linearly dependent with any other vector, because $0\mathbf{v} + \lambda \mathbf{0} = \mathbf{0}$.